# Unit test with Authlogic on Rails 3

Tags: unit-testing, authlogic, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to write some **unit test** with a logged user using Authlogic.  To start right, I used some code hosted in http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example.  But I get an error after **rake test**, because of "test_helper.rb" and the following class:

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  setup :activate_authlogic
end
```

Here is my error:

> NameError: undefined local variable or
>   method `activate_authlogic' for

I think this Authlogic example is mapped over Rails 2; maybe it's a little bit different on Rails 3.  Is there an other example where I can take example about unit test?

Many thanks.

Comment: you should accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 16):

Do you `require 'authlogic/test_case'` and `include Authlogic::TestCase`? 
I had a similar issue (using rspec, though) and read through the code at http://github.com/trevmex/authlogic_rails3_example

Comment: In mi case _Rails/3.2_ and _Authlogic/3.1.3_ only `require 'authlogic/test_case'` has been needed.

Answer (score 1):

As of Rails 3.1 and Authlogic 3.0.3, the only thing I've had to add to activate authlogic was

***features/support/env.rb***

```
Before do
  activate_authlogic
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't realize where to put `include Authlogic::TestCase`, so I put this after the requires in `spec_helper.rb` and it worked. There is a better place for it?

Comment: I put it in configuration block like this: `config.include Authlogic::TestCase`